# How to populate using mongoose? I have a problem

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm making a simple example of CRUD for a larger and open source project. Right now I want to populate with user data, I have already looked at the documentation and some forums and I am not able to solve the problem that is causing here.

The message in terminal "Populated User undefined"

Could anyone help?

userModel

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema =  mongoose.Schema;

var userSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String
    },
});
```

userController

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
User = mongoose.model('Users');

exports.create_a_user = function(req, res) {
    var new_user = new User(req.body);
    new_user.save(function(err, user) {
    if (err)
        res.send(err);
    res.json(user);
    });
};
```

msgModel

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('Users', userSchema);

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema =  mongoose.Schema;

var msgSchema = new Schema({
    title: {
        type: String
    },
    body: {
        type: String
    },
    created_date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    user : { 
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
        ref: 'User' 
    },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Messages', msgSchema);
```

msgController

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
Message = mongoose.model('Messages');

exports.list_all_messages = function (req, res) {
    Message.find({})
    .populate('user')
    .exec((err, msg) => {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);
        res.json(msg);
    });
};
```

Comment: do you assign user id to user field in the messageSchema , when you want to create new message?

Answer (score 0):

module.exports = mongoose.model('Users', userSchema);

maybe in msgSchema you have to reference 'users' instead of 'user'

Answer (score 0):

So, I found the error in the code, in the user's schema there was a lack of reference to the export of the name that was placed in the user's model.

```
user : { 
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
    ref: 'Users'
},
```

So,...

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('Users', userSchema);
```